# What is the extension that indicates the file will open in OSX Terminal utility?

Tags: macos, terminal

Is there an extension .XXX in OSX that is the extension assigned to the Terminal Utility by default?
Something like .ter? For example if the file has the extension .pdf it will be opened by preview by default.

Comment: What do you mean by "file will open"?  Do you mean launch an executable?

Comment: For example, in /usr/local/bin, many apps show up as "open in terminal apps" even though they do not seem to have an extension.

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The two filename extensions which will cause your script or other executable to be launched in a terminal session are `.tool` and `.command`

Note, the file must be set as executable.

example:
given your script `hello.txt`:

```
cp hello.txt hello.tool
chmod +x hello.tool
open hello.tool
```